# maven release with multi module project and main pom in sub-directory

Tags: maven, svn, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I'm working on a project, which originally was set up by a different author. Each module has its own directory. Also the main pom (`my-project-pom`), which includes the modules, is stored in a separate sub-directory. We're using subversion:

```
+-- branches
+-- tags
'-- trunk
     +-- my-project-pom
     +-- my-project-web
     +-- my-project-ear
     '-- README
```

Now I'm trying to setup the maven release plugin with following goals:

- Everything is included in the commit from maven release, also changes in the root README file
- SVN tags are automatically created in the proper repository directory `tags\<version>`

So my questions are:

- Is this possible at all, although the main pom is not in the root directory?
- How should I configure the `<connection>` and `<developerConnection>` URLs in `my-project-pom` to achieve this? Do I have to point directly to the trunk or to `trunk\my-project-pom` or something different
- Is there any other configuration required besides the `<scm>` configuration above and the definition of the plugin dependency - e.g. the `tagBase` setting?
- In which directory do I have to execute the `mvn release` commands?

Comment: You need to use maven as it was intended to be used, sort your directory structure out, then if you have a scm element you just need a mvn release:prepare repease:perform